# Altair - how to add lines inside chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, charts, altair

I am trying to add specific lines to a line graph in Altair, going from text to a certain point on the graph. I have added my current output here:

[image]

I am trying to end up with a chart like the one below, but I can't figure out how to add the lines correctly inside the graph.

[image]

Below is a df of the text and locations that need to be added at certain times. My question is - how can I add the lines inside the graph to show the specific times that these events occurred?

```
    date              count note
0   2017-08-27 00:15:00 4   Fight begins
1   2017-08-27 00:22:00 5   McGregor does OK \nin the early rounds
2   2017-08-27 00:53:00 4   Mayweather takes \nover and wins by \nTKO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are plotting the line.

When you specify the line using only x and y, it joins those lines and does not create a separate line

```
s ="""date,count,note
2017-08-27 00:15:00,4,Fight begins
2017-08-27 00:22:00,5,McGregor does OK \\nin the early rounds
2017-08-27 00:53:00,4,Mayweather takes \\nover and wins by \\nTKO"""
a_df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in s.split('\n')])
a_df = a_df.rename(columns=a_df.iloc[0]).drop(a_df.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)
a_df['count'] =a_df['count'].astype(int)
```

Dataframe:

```
date    count   note
0   2017-08-27 00:15:00 4   Fight begins
1   2017-08-27 00:22:00 5   McGregor does OK \nin the early rounds
2   2017-08-27 00:53:00 4   Mayweather takes \nover and wins by \nTKO
```

Using only `x` and `y` arguments

```
alt.Chart(a_df).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    y='count:Q',
    color=alt.value('red'),
)
```

[image]

You have to use `x1` and `y1` or at least one of them for what you are looking for. For example:

```
a_df['temp'] = a_df['count'] - 1 # change it according to your use case
alt.Chart(a_df).mark_line().encode(
    x='date:T',
    #x2='date:T',
    y='count:Q',
    y2='temp:Q',
    color=alt.value('red'),
)
```

[image]

The lines are vertical since `x` and `x2` are the same since we have not specified the value for `x2`. Change it according to your problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: This is great information and exactly what I'm looking for. I wish Altair had better information on this (and everything else) in their documentation.

Comment: The [documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html) does have this information, but the example plots don't have anything similar.